# problem with astroquery download from the MAST archive

Tags: python, astroquery

All,

While testing a python script, I noticed that retrieving data from the TIC catalog results in an error message, like this:

ticinfo = Catalogs.query_criteria(catalog="Tic", ID=tic).as_array()

requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='mast.stsci.edu', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /portal/Mashup/Mashup.asmx/columnsconfig (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7f670582d2e0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution'))

This mistake is temporary and did not happen last week.  Is it caused by the MAST server being overloaded  by too many requests ?

Comment: I tried the following and was able to get results. So maybe it was because MAST was being overloaded? 

`from astroquery.mast import Catalogs; print(Catalogs.query_criteria(catalog="Tic", ID=336732616).as_array())`

Comment: Potentially related git issue I opened: https://github.com/astropy/astropy/issues/12255

Comment: MAST reported intermittent network issues on Oct 19th. 
[See this twitter post](https://twitter.com/MAST_News/status/1450099870698725384)